# How can I pad a sequence of bytes in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, padding

I'm trying to encrypt files like PDFs or executables, but I can't pad it.

I try to read the file in this method:

```
with('file', 'rb') as file_read:
    line = file_read.read(n) --> n multple of 16
    encrypt(line, key)
```

Then I pass the line to my `encrypt` function, but when I reach a line that isn't a multiple of 16, my program crashes.

How can I correctly pad a sequence of bytes?

Comment: What are you using for the `encrypt` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simplified (edited) version of a previous answer.

---

Assuming a file is read in a loop using `line = f.read(N)` (where N is the block size) until EOF.

1) Trivial zero padding; just add this after the `read`:

```
elen = len(line) % N
if elen:
    line += bytes(N - elen)
```

Zero padding is the simplest, but has drawbacks.

---

2) PKCS#7 padding, N < 256; add this after the `read` and make sure the loop will be exited afterward:

```
if len(line) < N:
    elen = 1 + (len(line) - 1) % N
    line += bytes(elen for _ in range(elen))
```

---

Please note that reading from files differs from reading from network sockets. A buffer is needed to read blocks of fixed length from network.

Comment: How will you remove the bytes after decryption if the data might end on a null byte? That is why [PKCS#7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7) padding is generally used and not particularly more difficult, it just pads with the number of padding bytes.

Comment: @zaph I saw your earlier answer, but the original question lacks details. That's why I started the answer with a disclaimer and posted the most trivial case to have some code to begin with.

Comment: @VPfB i'm trying to encrypt only files.

Comment: This is the great thing about software development, it is very egalitarian in that everybody's methods are equal. It is not like engineering where methods have to be proved and the better methods must be used. We are free to ignore substantial research and do out own thing. I saw today a developer creating his own encryption, ignoring the tremendous work in creating, researching and vetting the standard methods just because he would rather not use some else's code. We are not locked into being professional, we are more like free-range coding monkeys. ;-)

Comment: @apollo9 Now we know that we can ignore partial network `read()`s. Let's concentrate on the main question. Please be more specific regarding the padding - could you answer zaph's question what encrypt function are you using?

Comment: @zaph nice man, but it's the first time that I try encrypt something and I used this code to understood how it works.

Comment: @apollo9 I was asking about the specific implementation you are using, please provide more information or a link to it.

Comment: @apollo9 AES can be used in many ways. Still don't know exactly what you are looking for. I have updated my answer with a simple PKCS#7 style padding. Hope it helps.

Comment: Note that PKCS#7 padding must be added even if the message is an exact multiple of the block size.

Comment: @zaph yes; in that case the very last file.read() encounters EOF, returns zero bytes, len is 0, elen is N (blocksize) and N bytes with value N are appended as padding. WAIT! apollo9 is not reading blocks from file in a loop!

Comment: The data is feed to the encryption process as blocks if it is a block based cipher. On encryption the output will always be an exact multiple of the block size because of the added padding. Then when reading the encrypted data the input will be an exact multiple of the block size. Let's say the last block ends with 0x01, Is that an encrypted byte or padding? The point is that if padding is specified it must always be added. Another way to look at is to examine the PKCS#7 padding algorithm and consider if all the cryptographic domain expert are stupid. Then re-examine all possible cases.

Comment: @apollo9 You are doing only one read. If the file is larger, only the first part of it will be processed. I should have noticed sooner.

Comment: @zaph I have already answered with yes. In PKCS#7 is padding ALWAYS required and I wrote my code accordingly. Just got a warning about extended discussion, so I'm stopping here right now.

Comment: Sorry, I mis-understood.

Comment: I'm not a native english speaker. Sorry if any of my comments started a misunderstanding.

Comment: I resolve using this pad function     
`return s  + bytes(bs - len(s) % bs)` where bs is my block size

Answer (score 2):

Most encryption implementations support a padding option, usually [PKCS#7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7) (née PKCS#5) that adds the padding on encryption and removed it on decryption.

Note: mcrypt does not support PKCS#7 padding, stay away from it.